# webViewDidFinishLoading not being called

Tags: ios, delegates

With the risk of double posting (I have found and studied similar questions, but the answers didn't seem to work for me):

In my ViewController.h I have this:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UIWebView * webView;
```

In my ViewController.m I have this:

```
@synthesize webView
```

and this:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoading:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"This doesn't output to the console");
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}
```

and in the ViewDidLoad I have this:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]]];
```

On my storyboard, I have placed a UIWebView, and connected it to 'webView'. I also set its delegate to ViewController.

[image: Like this:]

It seems to me that I am missing something in the whole chain of linked things, but I don't see what. I'm pretty sure it is something stupid, so don't hesitate to vote me down or curse at me. I just want to understand this.

Oh, and I tried adding webView.delegate=self to several suggested locations, but that didn't help either.

Thanks ahead

Comment: Double check the URL you're loading.

Comment: URL is loading and displaying fine

Comment: Try to set some kind of logs in webViewDidStartLoad: and webView:didFailLoadWithError: delegate methods. Probably you get error while loading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the method name is:

```
 - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

and not:

```
 - (void)webViewDidFinishLoading:(UIWebView *)webView
```

(remove ..ing)

Comment: That's it. I must have copied some crusty code. That also includes - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request Is that misspelled as well? It's not being called.

Comment: @Sjakelien - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType

Comment: @Sjakelien check the documentation ;-) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webViewDidFinishLoad: